# How I can retrieve the AWS services statuses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, status

How I can retrieve the AWS services statuses programmatically? Is there any API which will provide me the status like below URL, which can give me health status of desired services which my cloud formation stack will use.

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the status of the **services that you are using**.

For API access, see: [AWS Health API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)

> The AWS Health API provides programmatic access to the AWS Health
>   information that is presented in the AWS Personal Health Dashboard.
>   You can get information about events that affect your AWS resources